# Not able to pass the current user in Delete trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete, triggers

I am creating a trigger for a delete query, so if any one deletes the row from `Tasklists`, the table it will copy two rows to the `Tasklistslog` table.
One row will be existing data with modified by from original table saying rows updated. Another row will be requiring modified by column name to be current user which returns from MVC Model (i.e.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name), and not from main table saying row deleted.

I am not able to pass (i.e.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) to trigger
below is trigger what values I want.... I do have another table from which I am getting the username converted to full name & same for branch.

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[tasklistdelete]
ON [dbo].[Tasklists] 
After delete
AS
declare
@Task_Id    int,
@TaskName   nvarchar,
@Discription    nvarchar,
@Frequency  nvarchar,
@Branch int,
@Duedate    date,
@status nvarchar,
@Performer  int,
@Active nvarchar,
@Recurrence nvarchar,
@comments   nvarchar,
@modifiedby nvarchar;

select @Task_Id=i.Task_Id from deleted i; 
select @TaskName=i.TaskName from deleted i; 
select @Discription=i.Discription from deleted i; 
select @Frequency=i.Frequency from deleted i; 
select @Branch=i.Branch from deleted i; 
select @Duedate=i.Duedate from deleted i; 
select @status=i.status from deleted i; 
select @Performer=i.Performer from deleted i; 
select @Active=i.Active from deleted i; 
select @Recurrence=i.Recurrence from deleted i; 
select @comments=i.comments from deleted i;
select @modifiedby=i.modifiedby from deleted i;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Tasklistslog(Task_Idlog,TaskNamelog,Discriptionlog,Frequencylog,Branchlog,Duedatelog,statuslog,Performerlog,Activelog,Recurrencelog,commentslog,lastupdatedby,auditaction,logtime)
select Task_Id,TaskName,Discription,Frequency,Legislation,
(select Branch from Branch where Branch_id = @Branch),
@Duedate,status,
(select Displayname from Users where User_id = @Performer),
Active,
Recurrence,
comments,
@modifiedby,'Task Deleted',GETDATE()
from deleted ; 
END;
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `DELETE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @Task_Id=i.Task_Id from deleted i;` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: From my web site there will be always only one row deletion.there will be no multiple deletion, i will make both changes as per suggetions, if any idea how to achieve the same...